# Create Generic Class Instance from Static Method in a Derived Class

Tags: c#, generics, static-methods

I have a class in C# with a template and static method similar to

```
class BClass<T>
{
  public static BClass<T> Create()
  {
    return new BClass<T>();
  }
 }
```

From this I derive a class and specify a template parameter to the base class

```
class DClass : BClass<int> { }
```

A problem occurs when I try to use the static method to create an instance of D

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    DClass d = DClass.Create();
  }
}
```

Gives a compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Test.BClass<int> ' to 'Test.DClass'."

Adding the below cast leads to a runtime casting exception.

```
DClass d = (DClass)DClass.Create();
```

Is there any succint way to allow the static method to create instances of the derived class? Ideally I would like the equivalent of a c++ typedef and I don't want the below syntax (which does work).

```
BClass<int> d = DClass.Create();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**, by having a type reference to the type itself. Note that in the .NET world we are talking of generics, not templates, which do have important differences in the way they work.

```
class BClass<T, TSelf> where TSelf: BClass<T, TSelf>, new() {
    public static TSelf Create() {
        return new TSelf();
    }
}

class DClass: BClass<int, DClass> {}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        DClass d = DClass.Create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't think a class could reference itself as a type parameter in its superclass? Chicken-and-egg paradox or something...

Comment: Clever AND a bit bizarre! ;) The only disadvantage I see here is that it seems there'd never be any way to instantiate a plain old `BClass<T, TSelf>`, as in the OP's original code.

Comment: @Peter, I actually have used this successfully quite a lot. For instance it also allows you to create a better clone method because it eliminates the need to re-cast, etc.

Comment: @Dan Tao, right, that basically only works for "abstract" classes which are then inherited.

Comment: @Lucero, that is pretty cool. Guess it was similar to what I've tried before, `MyClass : ISomeGenericInterface<MyClass>`... which does not work :)

Comment: @Peter, `MyClass: ISomeGenericInterface<MyClass>` does work fine for me. You must have tried something else. ;)

Comment: @Lucero - ouch... man, what was it then?? perhaps `MyClass<T> : T`. Ohwell :)

Comment: This is a good answer, but note that if you have another class `EClass : DClass`, then `EClass.Create()` will return a `DClass` instance, not an `EClass` instance, which may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that what you want is for `DClass` to be an alias for `BClass<int>`. But that's not what you have here. What you have is that `DClass` **derives from** `BClass<int>`. Thus calling `DClass.Create();` creates a `BClass<int>`, which is *not* a `DClass` (it's the other way around).

This might make it clearer. Suppose you had this hierarchy:

```
class Rectangle {
    static Rectangle Create() {
        return new Rectangle();
    }
}

class Square : Rectangle { }

// code elsewhere
var shape = Square.Create(); // you might want this to return a square,
                             // but it's just going to return a rectangle
```

One option to get something like the functionality you want might be to define your `Create` method like this:

```
static TClass Create<TClass>() where TClass : BClass<T>, new() {
    return new TClass();
}

// code elsewhere
var shape = DClass.Create<DClass>();
```

That's a bit messy, though (and also requires that you write a parameterless constructor for `DClass`). If you're dead set on using a `Create` method for the instantiation of your objects, consider writing a factory class for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BClass<T>
    {
        public static T1 Create<T1, T2>() where T1 : BClass<T2>, new()
        {
            return new T1();
        }
    }

    class DClass : BClass<int> { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DClass d = DClass.Create<DClass, int>();
        }
    }
```